# Unable to add two layers in Keras of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a simple regression model as below. The layers `layer_abc` and `layer_efg` both have `(None, 5)` as output, so their output have same dimension and can be added. Thus I want to unhide the code `#keras.layers.Add()(['layer_abc', 'layer_efg'])`. But whenever I do this, I got an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`. If I didn't unhide this line, then the code is fine.

How can I add the two layers without having error? Many thanks!

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from scipy import misc
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, Activation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_images=np.array([[[0],[1],[2]],[[0],[0],[2]],[[1],[1],[1]],[[1],[0],[1]]])
train_labels=np.array([[1],[0],[1],[0]])

model = keras.Sequential([  
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(3, 1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='layer_abc'),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='layer_efg'),
    #keras.layers.Add()(['layer_abc', 'layer_efg']),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax),    
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy','mean_squared_error'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=2)
```

Comment: Why do you need to declare them sequentially, just to add them together? If the layers are exactly the same, why not just a call to a Dense layer with 10 units?

Comment: You will need functional API and then use model.merge

Comment: @JimmyOnThePage Because in my original model, `layer_abc` and `layer_efg` are separated by some other layers as well. For simplicity, I just put them as consecutive layers here,  but they are not.

Comment: @anand_v.singh For my case here, `layer_abc` and `layer_efg` are not parallel. `layer_abc` is placed before `layer_efg`. What I am trying to do here, is to create a shortcut, similar to the ResNet ( https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning-with/9781788624336/9be37dc9-80b6-4bb7-a6eb-4fc92b7fd3d9.xhtml ). I think model.merge is mainly for the parallel addition, but not for the case of shortcut?

Comment: Shortcuts don't fit the the Sequential model. With Sequential, each layer is the sole input to the next. Layers don't get to have multiple inputs (though what's *inside* a given layer might not be sequential). `layer_abc` is shared, and you need to use the functional API for shared layers.
Further, [it's not allowed (or deprecated) to merge two Sequential models](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6357).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functional API like this to do the Add, for single output between 0 and 1, use the sigmoid activation for the output:

```
input = keras.layers.Input((3,1))
x1 =  keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_abc')(input)
x2 =  keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_efg')(input)
x =  keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(x)
model = keras.models.Model(input, output)
```

This might work:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(3, 1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='layer_abc'),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='layer_efg')])

model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(model.layers[1].output, x)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This approach would require significant rewriting work for the original model. Is there a way to add them by still using the `keras.Sequential([ ])` approach? Or can I do it without creating new variables `x1` and `x2`?